# How to select Gender from Dropdown list using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, list, automation, dropdown

I'm stuck again in how to select the Gender (Male / Female) from a dropdown list in a Website. My current script works, apart for the gender part:

```
Sub MERF()

  Dim IE As Object
  Dim doc As HTMLDocument
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.navigate "https://portal.spsc.gov.sa/MEH/Default.aspx?Id=386"
  
  Do While IE.Busy
     Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
  Loop
  
  Set doc = IE.document

  'IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Mr_Txt").Value = "very cute"
  doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Event_Date_Txt").Value = Sheet1.Range("F34").Value
  doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Wasfaty_Chk_1").Click
  Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05")
  doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Wasfaty_Other").Value = Sheet1.Range("T34").Value
  doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Mr_Txt").Value = Sheet1.Range("B34").Value
  doc.getElementById("select2-ContentPlaceHolder1_Gender_Drop-container").Click
  doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Event_Desc_Txt").Value = Sheet1.Range("M34").Value
  doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtReporterComment").Value = Sheet1.Range("Q34").Value
  doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Reporter_Name_Txt").Value = "name"
  doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Reporter_Email_Txt").Value = "mail"
  doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Reporter_Mobile_Txt").Value = "xxxx"

  
End Sub
```

I tried GetElementByID and GetElementByClassName for the Gender field but it does not work. I added a value Male, but it doesn't want to appear in the text field, even after adding Click.

It's blocking for this specific line: doc.getElementById("select2-ContentPlaceHolder1_Gender_Drop-container").Click
Blocking means that, if I keep the above line, it does not click on the Gender dropdown list, and does not run the following line in the script, i.e. this one:

```
doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Event_Desc_Txt").Value = Sheet1.Range("M34").Value
```

Regarding some information on the HTML on the page, I can do **Inspect** on the Gender field in the website, then post in here [I'll need my laptop for that]. Will that help?

I'm a total newbie with VBA, so please excuse me for not giving required detail.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's blocking for this specific line: doc.getElementById("select2-ContentPlaceHolder1_Gender_Drop-container").Click

Comment: Have you tried adding [breakpoints](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/debugging-vba-code-adding-breakpoints/) to better help you diagnose the problem?